# Why isn't $26^6 - 24^6$ the number of possible permutations of the alphabet without "a" and "b"?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

The question is "How many strings of six lower case letters from the English alphabet contain the letters $a$ and $b$?"

Why doesn't $26^6 - 24^6$ work?

$26^6$ is all the possible permutations of $26$ letters MINUS all permutations without $a$ nor $b$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You can always try counting with smaller numbers first.  How many strings of $2$ characters from the alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ contain both $a$ and $b$? You have two: $ab$, $ba$.  Why doesn't $2 = 3^2 - 1^2$?

Comment: 'contain the letters a and b' is a bit ambiguous. What the problem says is BOTH a and b or  at least one a and one b

Answer (score 9):

You want to count the strings the contain $a$ AND $b$. What you should subtract is thus the number of strings that don’t contain both $a$ and $b$, meaning that they are allowed to contain $a$ but not $b$, and $b$ but not $a$.

Answer (score 2):

For your mistake see the answer of Mankind.

This answer tells you how to do it correctly.

---

Let $A$ denote the collection of strings that do not contain letter $a$ and let $B$ denote the collection of strings that do not contain letter $b$.

Then the number of strings that contain letter $a$ **and** letter $b$ equals: $$|A^{\complement}\cap B^{\complement}|=26^6-|A\cup B|=26^6-|A|-|B|+|A\cap B|=26^6-2\cdot25^6+24^6$$

Further for completeness observe that: $$|A^{\complement}\cup B^{\complement}|=26^6-|A\cap B|=26^6-24^6$$counting the number of strings that contain letter $a$ **or** letter $b$ (where it is allowed to contain both).

Comment: Still waking up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When facing a problem like this solve it for small numbers.

Our alphabet is {a,b,c}.  How many 2 character long strings?  $3^2 = 9$.  What are they?

```
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```

How many 2 character long strings with a or b?  $1^3 = 1$.  It is `ccc`.

How many 3 character long strings with both a and b?

```
ab
ba
```

2.  Using your method, you would get 9-1=8.  Now, that minus is actually taking a specific one way, so we can see what 8 we counted here:

```
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
```

we can see that we counted every string with *either* an `a` or a `b`, not string that have *both*.

Now we can count strings that do contain a single letter this way.  If we take away the lines that don't contain `a`:

```
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```

minus:

```
bb
bc
cb
cc
```

We get $3^2 - (3-1)^2 = 5$:

```
aa
ab
ac
ba
ca
```

which is the right answer for the number of 2 character strings that contain `a`.